# Simple arithmetic operations on elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I shift the first element of a list by 148.38 and the second element by -38.45? The data

```
417864.69,5332858.39,0.00,3629.824,2,0,0,0.10
417864.94,5332858.82,0.00,3885.531,2,0,1,0.10
417865.19,5332859.25,0.00,3647.226,2,0,2,0.10
417865.44,5332859.69,0.00,-884.887,2,0,3,0.10
...
...
```

are imported via

```
w = Import["a.010.csv", "TSV"];
```

(by the way: the data are rounded if I use "CSV" - I don't know why ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read through the help docs on accessing [list elements](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ElementsOfLists.html).

If your data is a list of lists in the following form

```
w = {{417864.69,5332858.39,0.00,3629.824,2,0,0,0.10},
     {417864.94,5332858.82,0.00,3885.531,2,0,1,0.10}}
```

Then you can use the short form of the `Part` and `Span` commands operate on elements like this:

```
w[[;;,1]] = w[[;;,1]] + 148.38;
w[[;;,2]] = w[[;;,2]] - 38.45;
AccountingForm@NumberForm[#, 10] & /@ w
```

which results in this output

```
{{418013.07,5332819.94,0.,3629.824,2,0,0,0.1}
 {418013.32,5332820.37,0.,3885.531,2,0,1,0.1}}
```